# Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff Lemma

Tags: operators, terminology, group-theory, commutator, lie-algebra

I've seen it called the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff (BCH) formula, the BCH lemma, the braiding relation, the Hadamard Lemma. I am referring to the formula
$$
e^{X} Y e^{-X}=e^{\mathrm{ad}_{X}} Y=Y+[X, Y]+\frac{1}{2 !}[X,[X, Y]]+\frac{1}{3 !}[X,[X,[X, Y]]]+\cdots.
$$
As i understand it, it is actually a lemma used in proving the BCH theorem. But is there an accepted name for this formula?

Comment: It's rare to find a single name to represent a formula, or a lemma or identity; but this section of the Wikipedia Article outlines the relation between the two quite well https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula . The one in your question would be the "BCH Identity", and the other one would be the "Lemma"

Comment: No, there is no standardized name. Germans use "Hausdorff L", many Russians "Hadamard's L", and, if you know *some* group theory, you'd appreciate the term "adjoint action L". If you are on the web, you'd be silly to not use the standard WP section link you got  in the other comment. I suggest you move the question to [HSMSE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com), as there is no physics question here.

Comment: E.g. see prop 5.2 of [this](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02102819).  For a Lie algebra, this evokes Hadamard's Analysis Lemma, the basis elements of the Lie Algebra corresponding  to a finite number of powers. The right-hand side is a *finite* sum, instead of an infinite expansion.

Comment: Related Math.SE questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3703509/11127 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/711308/11127